# Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "obj" is null - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've been experimenting with a program in JavaFX that displays three images side-by-side along with three buttons below them. When you click a button, the card the button is below should be swapped for another image. I am attempting to use a single event handler for this and as such need to declare my imageView objects and buttons outside of the start() method. However, I am getting a NullPointerException on a line of code that does not even exist within the program.

Here is my code. All of this code is within the same Main class.

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    //IMAGES
    //img 1 setup
    final String img1Path = "src/application/c1.gif";
    ImageView img1;
    boolean img1Flip = false;
    
    //img 2 setup
    final String img2Path = "src/application/c2.gif";
    ImageView img2;
    boolean img2Flip = false;
    
    //img 3 setup
    final String img3Path = "src/application/c3.gif";
    ImageView img3;
    boolean img3Flip = false;
    
    //img 4 setup
    final String img4Path = "src/application/b1fv.gif";
    
    //BUTTONS
    //button 1 setup
    Button button1;
    
    //button 2 setup
    Button button2;
    
    //button 3 setup
    Button button3;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage1) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Compiled."); //debug
        //image view setup
        img1 = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(img1Path))); //creates an image view
        img2 = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(img2Path))); //creates an image view
        img3 = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream(img3Path))); //creates an image view
        
        //button setup
        button1 = new Button("Flip");
        button1.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) new ButtonHandler());
        //button1.setId("button1");
        
        button2 = new Button("Flip");
        button2.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) new ButtonHandler());
        //button2.setId("button2");
        
        button3 = new Button("Flip");
        button3.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) new ButtonHandler());
        //button3.setId("button3");
        
        //scene setup
        final int sceneW = 400;
        final int sceneH = 200;
        
        //stage setup
        final String stageTitle = "FlipImages";
        
        System.out.println("Initialized."); //debug
        try {
            //STAGE SETUP
            System.out.println("Setting Up"); //debug
            stage1.setTitle(stageTitle);
            FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane, sceneW, sceneH);
            pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            //ADDING TO SCENE
            System.out.println("Formatting."); //debug
            HBox imagePanel = new HBox(img1, img2, img3);
            HBox buttonPanel = new HBox();
            imagePanel.setSpacing((double) 5);
            buttonPanel.setSpacing((double) 10);
            pane.getChildren().addAll(imagePanel, buttonPanel);
            
            //FINAL STEPS
            System.out.println("Generating."); //debug
            stage1.setScene(scene1);
            stage1.setResizable(false);
            stage1.show();
            } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Caught."); //debug
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        public void handle(ActionEvent a) {
            try {
                System.out.println("handle Image Creation"); //debug
                //regular image setup
                Image img1unflip = new Image(new FileInputStream(img1Path)); //creates an image
                Image img2unflip = new Image(new FileInputStream(img2Path)); //creates an image
                Image img3unflip = new Image(new FileInputStream(img3Path)); //creates an image
                
                //flipped image setup
                Image imgFlipped = new Image(new FileInputStream(img4Path)); //creates an image
            
                System.out.println("Obtaining Source"); //debug
                //String callId = ((Node) a.getSource()).getId(); //doesn't work well
                
                Object source = a.getSource();
                
                System.out.println("Flipping"); //debug
                if (source == button1) {
                    if (img1Flip == false) {
                        img1 = new ImageView(imgFlipped);
                        }
                    else {
                        img1 = new ImageView(img1unflip);
                        }
                    }
                else if (source == button2) {
                    if (img2Flip == false) {
                        img2 = new ImageView(imgFlipped);
                        }
                    else {
                        img2 = new ImageView(img2unflip);
                        }
                    }
                else if (source == button3) {
                    if (img3Flip == false) {
                        img3 = new ImageView(imgFlipped);
                        }
                    else {
                        img3 = new ImageView(img3unflip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Caught: handle"); //debug
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Here is the console output. Notice that none of my debug statements are printed.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "obj" is null
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

I would like to know why this error is taking place and how to fix it.

Comment: Because “obj” is null?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I see that, but I didn't write anything referring to "obj" or "Object.getClass()"

Comment: Where is the "launch()" method defined?

Comment: @NomadMaker launch() is built into the Application superclass and sets up the JavaFX, and calls the start() method which I defined.

Comment: As noted in the duplicate, you just have to make your main method `static` to solve this problem.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize I missed it.